# How do I configure Visual Studio Online to run a custom unit test framework?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, mspec, nspec

I'm trying to make the Visual Studio Online build service run my nSpec tests. I've downloaded the nSpec test adapter (which works fine locally), unzipped the DLLs and uploaded those to a separate TFS repository. I've [configured the hosted build controller](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/03/03/how-to-make-your-discoverer-executor-extension-visible-to-ute.aspx) and set the reference to this repo.

As far as I know this should be sufficient, but my build simply doesn't find any unit tests. If I try to edit the build definition -> Click Process, it downloads custom assemblies it looks like, but it just writes this message to the console:

> No assemblies were found in the custom assembly path. The assemblies may not exist or you may not have permissions to read them. Contact your Team Foundation Administrator for more information.

I've tried the same procedure with mSpec as well, but exactly the same happens here. nUnit seems to work though, but if I'm not entirely wrong, that might actually be installed already on hosted build server.

Comment: You should use nuget. That would probably solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this requires the nSpec plugin to be installed on the build server and the TFS Hosted Build servers and you can only use the plugins provided. I believe that the servers only currently support MSTest, nUnit, and xUnit.

To get this working you will need to create your own custom build server. You can install a build server on Azure and install the tools you need. Then you can run your own build configuration there.